# Most elegant way to secure that a thread is finished while some task got done

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, timing

so I've managed to end my thread when a specific thing has happened,

BUT I want to secure myself in case that the specific thing I've mentioned didn't happen, 
so I won't end up in an infinite loop inside my thread.

so what I did is using a timer of 5 minutes just in case to reassure that this thread will die somehow even when the "while" condition isn't met.
I did it like so:

```
shouldRun = true;
doSomething();

Thread myThread = new Thread(() -> {
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long end = start + 60*1000*5;
   try {
       while (shouldRun && System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
           if (!someCondition()) {
                doAnotherThing();
              }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
                logger.error("Thread has failed while running with an exception error: {} ", e);
        }
    }).start();

doTaskThatTakesOneMinuteToRun();

shouldRun = false;
```

This logic above works, but I wondered if there's a more elegant/professional/proper way to achieve what I'm doing there and end the thread by timing if the "while" condition that is 
"shouldRun" is never false because the method before is stuck or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the while loop to run very often, you can replace it with a for loop and add a `Thread.sleep(millis)`. This way the time it will run will be roughly the number of iteration multiplied by the sleep time (if the other operations in the loop are fast enough to be trascurable). A for loop without the sleep seems more unpredictable.

You could also call `Thread.interrupt()` later from some other part of the code and check for `Thread.isInterrupted()`, but this wouldn't be much different than changing the value of `shouldRun` and since you didn't considered this option, it probably isn't viable in your case.